# How to print elements of a 2D array with different lengths in an aligned manner?

Tags: javascript

I have a 2-D array:

```
board_grid = [
    ["4",     "167",    "2",    "5",  "167",  "16",   "3",   "8",  "9"  ],
    ["13789", "13789",  "3789", "79", "4",    "189",  "2",   "6",  "5"  ],
    ["89",    "689",    "5",    "2",  "3",    "689",  "1",   "4",  "7"  ],
    ["389",   "389",    "1",    "6",  "5",    "2",    "48",  "7",  "48" ],
    ["6",     "78",     "78",   "1",  "9",    "4",    "5",   "3",  "2"  ],
    ["2",     "5",      "4",    "3",  "8",    "7",    "6",   "9",  "1"  ],
    ["5",     "246789", "6789", "79", "267",  "3",    "478", "1",  "468"],
    ["1378",  "123678", "3678", "4",  "1267", "156",  "9",   "25", "68" ],
    ["179",   "124679", "679",  "8",  "1267", "1569", "47",  "25", "3"  ]
]
```

I want to transform this `array` into a `string`, such that all elements are displayed as the same as above (i.e., each element of the same row/column are perfectly **aligned**). The square brackets, double quotes, commas don't necessarily have to be printed. Just newlines and whitespaces are enough to make each element distinguishable.

I actually want to display this string in the `alert` block.

The attempt I have tried:

```
function board_grid_to_display_string(board_grid) {
    var V_PADDING = " "; // Insert after each square
    var H_PADDING = '\n'; // Insert after each row
    var V_BOX_PADDING = "  "; // Box vertical padding
    var H_BOX_PADDING = '\n'; // Box horizontal padding

    var display_string = "";
    var i = 0;

    for (var r = 0; r < 9; ++r) {
        for (var c = 0; c < 9; ++c) {
            var square = board_grid[r][c];
            // Add the square and vertical padding
            display_string += square + V_PADDING;
            // Vertical edge of a box, insert vertical box padding
            if (i % 3 === 2) {
                display_string += V_BOX_PADDING;
            }
            // End of a line, insert horizontal padding
            if (i % 9 === 8) {
                display_string += H_PADDING;
            }
            // Horizontal edge of a box, insert horizontal box padding
            if (i % 27 === 26) {
                display_string += H_BOX_PADDING;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    return display_string;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: where do you want to print it?

Comment: @charlietfl added. Thanks for heads-up!

Comment: Are you asking how to make a table from some data?

Comment: To make the array display 1 subarray display each line, you could use `array.join('\n').toString()`, but this will not solve the space problem

Comment: @Andy I was thinking of just transforming the 2D array into a `string` containing some newlines and whitespace. But a `table` seems also fine, as long as the elements can be aligned when printed to the console.

Comment: the alert boxes in javascript use a proportional font, so it is not possible to make such alignments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following flattens the whole array to reduce down the longest string length then uses [String.proptotype.padEnd()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) to add extra spaces as needed.

The outer map is joined with the line break and the inner map pads each element and is joined with a single space between each column. You can adjust as needed

```js
// get maximum element string length
const mLen = grid.flat().reduce((a,c) => Math.max(c.length,a), 0);

const res = grid.map(arr => arr.map(s => s.padEnd(mLen,' ')).join(' ')).join('\n')

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
const grid = [
    ["4",     "167",    "2",    "5",  "167",  "16",   "3",   "8",  "9"  ],
    ["13789", "13789",  "3789", "79", "4",    "189",  "2",   "6",  "5"  ],
    ["89",    "689",    "5",    "2",  "3",    "689",  "1",   "4",  "7"  ],
    ["389",   "389",    "1",    "6",  "5",    "2",    "48",  "7",  "48" ],
    ["6",     "78",     "78",   "1",  "9",    "4",    "5",   "3",  "2"  ],
    ["2",     "5",      "4",    "3",  "8",    "7",    "6",   "9",  "1"  ],
    ["5",     "246789", "6789", "79", "267",  "3",    "478", "1",  "468"],
    ["1378",  "123678", "3678", "4",  "1267", "156",  "9",   "25", "68" ],
    ["179",   "124679", "679",  "8",  "1267", "1569", "47",  "25", "3"  ]
]

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant answer! One question: What adjustments should I add if I want the string also to be aligned when displayed in `alert(res)` instead of `console.log(res)`?

Comment: Should be the same in an alert

Comment: No...they are misaligned when displayed in `alert`.

Comment: Might be that alerts have a maximum amount of consecutive spaces allowed and sanitize the string to remove what is over the limit. In most web apps if an alert was needed it would typically be done with an html modal. The native alert can't be styled and doesn't accept any html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's the best idea but

- Get the greatest number
- Count how many digit have this number
- for each value in your array -> add many space in string

For your exemple, your greatest number is 246789 so it have 6 digits. 
Take any number in array like 48 (it have 2 digits) 
6 - 2 = 4 
Add 4 spaces before this value

Answer (score 0):

You could pad the strings after geeting the max length of each column.

```js
const
    board_grid = [["4", "167", "2", "5", "167", "16", "3", "8", "9"], ["13789", "13789", "3789", "79", "4", "189", "2", "6", "5"], ["89", "689", "5", "2", "3", "689", "1", "4", "7"], ["389", "389", "1", "6", "5", "2", "48", "7", "48"], ["6", "78", "78", "1", "9", "4", "5", "3", "2"], ["2", "5", "4", "3", "8", "7", "6", "9", "1"], ["5", "246789", "6789", "79", "267", "3", "478", "1", "468"], ["1378", "123678", "3678", "4", "1267", "156", "9", "25", "68"], ["179", "124679", "679", "8", "1267", "1569", "47", "25", "3"]],
    alignment = 'padEnd',
    sizes = board_grid.reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => Math.max(v.length, r[i] || 0)), []),
    result = board_grid.map(a => a.map((s, i) => s[alignment](sizes[i])));

result.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```